# VueJs - Unexpected token '?'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I added a new package.
After that when i run my project the compiler gives me unexpected token error because doesn't undertand question mark character.
eg "defaultedOptions.onSuccess?.(data);"

I tried to add transpileDependencies setting in app.config.js but continues to give me the same problem.

Comment: Check you babel config,  see if you have the plugin configured : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining . And also, usually, packages provides dist files, that are already built. if it's the case try to import from that instead of the source.

Comment: You most likely need to update your Node.js to higher version, I believe 16+ supports optional chaining